# Significado de "transparência" em possível duplo sentido

Tags: semântica

Seja o texto:

"As memórias síncronas de acesso aleatório dinâmico (SDRAM) precisam ser refrescadas (Refresh), isto é, sofrem uma recarga periódica para evitar perda de informações - essa ação é *realizada de forma **transparente** ao usuário, pelo sistema de memória*."

Há duas semânticas possíveis para o termo transparente, isso foi removido de uma questão de concurso e caiu na minha prova (não tenho fonte)... a questão era se a frase era Verdadeira ou Falsa.

A primeira semântica: transparente, de tal forma que o usuário não precisa agir, não percebe, é automático. *Isso torna a questão verdadeira*.

A segunda semântica: transparente, de tal forma que o usuário é impossibilitado de matematicamente calcular com exatidão o Refresh. *Isso torna a questão falsa*. Ou outras semânticas... que eu nem imagino.

Gostaria de, por favor, saber a opinião de algumas pessoas sobre - eu por exemplo, pensei primeiro na primeira semântica e coloquei como verdadeiro, e errei a questão..

Qual é o significado de transparência quando se aplica entre esses termos? No qual "ação X" é transparente a "personagem".

Comment: *Transparente*, em conotação, costuma significar *de forma honesta, com ciência daqueles a quem concirna, exposta publicamente*. Nesse caso, entretanto, por contexto, diria que significa *desapercebido*.

Comment: Semprei achei que o "D" em SDRAM vinha de "Dynamic", dinâmico e não duplo. É esse caráter dinâmico que leva à necessidade de serem refrescadas essas memórias.

Comment: Olá, agradeço as respostas, interessante compreender o significado formal, pois no dicionário não consta essa clareza neste contexto e poderia dar outros sentidos.. acabei decidindo verificar aqui por uma resposta de pessoas estudiosas.

Consta na Wikipedia inglesa que a frase é correta e o sentido semântico padrão é justamente de "desapercebido pelo usuário".
[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_refresh)
`[...]This process is conducted automatically in the background by the memory circuitry and is transparent to the user.`

Comment: @AiltonAndradedeOliveira obrigado pela correção, de fato eu escrevi errado... alterei para Dinâmico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No contexto (ciência da computação), *transparent* na verdade tem um significado [mais próximo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_(human%E2%80%93computer_interaction)) de "**invisível** ao usuário", portanto similar à tua primeira semântica.

Sobre o porquê da tua opção ter sido considerada incorreta, seria possível que a existência do comando [*auto refresh*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_dynamic_random-access_memory#Auto_refresh) para os chips SDRAM significa que o *refresh* **não** é necessariamente transparente?

Comment: A questão era justamente "A frase seguinte é verdadeira ou falsa", só como referência a Wiki inglesa no tópico de "Memory Refresh" contextualiza "transparent" igualmente como você definiu, portanto creio que nada há a se fazer.
Foi bom para confirmar o conhecimento do termo, em contexto pouco usado, e talvez tenha serventia no futuro - talvez quem tenha escrito a questão não tenha um bom conhecimento do português.

[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_refresh)
`[...]This process is conducted automatically in the background by the memory circuitry and is transparent to the user.`

Comment: @MateusMatucumaTeixeira Acabo de complementar minha resposta com a questão das SDRAM terem um comando de 'refrescada' - pelo menos quando esse comando é explicitamente dado, eu diria que não se pode afirmar que a refrescada é transparente, afinal ela pode ser ativada intencional e explicitamente.

Comment: [Dynamic Random Access Memory - 2016 Spring Lectures CS350C](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~hunt/class/2016-spring/cs350c/lectures/DRAMNotes.pdf)

Página 4:

````

Micron MT48LC32M8A2TG‐6A: 8 Meg x 8 x 4 banks, 256 Mbib [...]

• Auto precharge, includes concurrent auto precharge and auto refresh modes

• Self refresh mode

• Auto refresh

- 64ms, 8192-cycle (commercial and industrial)

- 16ms, 8192-cycle (automotive)

````

Comment: [...] Página 12:
````
AUTO REFRESH is used during normal operation of the SDRAM and is analogous to CAS#-BEFORE-RAS# (CBR) refresh in conventional DRAMs. [...]
All active banks must be precharged prior to issuing an AUTO REFRESH command.
The AUTO REFRESH command should not be issued until the minimum tRP (Row Precharge Time) has been met after the PRECHARGE command, as shown in Bank/Row Activation (page 51 of the data sheet).
The addressing is generated by the internal refresh controller. This makes the address bits a “Don’t Care” during an AUTO REFRESH command.
````

Comment: O problema dos comentários é não poder formatar corretamente, todavia esses textos descrevem melhor o Auto Refresh e comprovam que o controlador de memória tem absoluto controle também do refrescamento da DRAM, o que é interessante; isso propõe que de fato não há transparência para o controlador, porém ainda há para o usuário final.. ou não.. se obter controle do Kernel, é possível alterar os parâmetros do controlador e realizar perda de dados intencional.

Comment: Todavia quando se analisa o que eu creio ser uma patente e uma pesquisa, o termo transparente ao usuário se torna verdadeiro novamente..
[SMS Power - RAM Development](http://www.smspower.org/Development/RAM) `The self-refresh mode provides transparent refresh without system overhead`
[IEEE Transparent-refresh DRAM (TReD) using dual-port DRAM cell, 1988](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/20796/) -- o que são contradições semânticas e lógicas, o que se conclui nada.. que é do contexto que a pessoa continha para escrever.

Comment: Seguindo os links fica claro que não conheço quase nada sobre o assunto. :-) Em geral talvez seja importante especificar *para quem* é (ou não) transparente, como você menciona, mas acho mesmo que valeria a pena você postar a questão, reformulada, em outro SE (não sei qual, talvez eletrônica) - e voltar aqui para contar o que descobrir. ;-)

Comment: Ahh.. pela minha experiência, esta questão em especial não vale posteriores discussões - acaba que é bem o que disse, especificar _para quem é_, e para mim valeu a pena o pensamento e raciocínio, eu realmente concluo que esse tipo de questão foi mal formulada e é algo que, se antes dessa troca de ideias eu provavelmente faria errado também no lugar do criador da questão, agora termino com um melhor pensamento de especificar - é algo que falta na computação como um todo, por isso os termos são ambíguos, não existe um jeito padrão de programação, e cada um faz o seu conceito.. Agradeço muito! :)

Answer (score -2):

A primeira resposta que te deram por este site está ridiculamente errada. Transparente não significa "invisível" como ele disse. Significa na verdade, obviamente, translucido, ou seja, no contexto da frase significa que as INFORMAÇÕES são VISÍVEIS ao usuário. Repare que não é uma questão de semântica não, porque "transparente" só tem um significado, que é o de tornar algo visível, que teoricamente de outra forma não seria visível ou compreensível, por exemplo, de materiais não translúcidos como o vidro.

Comment: Se a outra resposta está errada, como explicas então o artigo citado da Wikipedia sobre [Transparency (human–computer interaction)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_(human%E2%80%93computer_interaction))? E o artigo científico linkado da WP, em http://ijcsits.org/papers/vol2no62012/42vol2no6.pdf , está então também errado quando diz e.g. «Any  change  in  a  computing system,  such  as  new feature  or  new  component, is transparent if  the system  after  change  adheres  to  previous  external  interface  as  much  as  possible  while  changing  its  internal  behaviour»?

Comment: Má formatação, referência e acusação a outra pergunta, afirmações evidentemente falsas (vide: 'nao é uma questão de semântica não'), e falta de fontes. -1

Comment: A possibilidade de alguns do PT-BR levarem a um sentido antônimo do PT-PT não pode ser excluída, porém a transparência de fato está relacionada também à invisibilidade ou não visão: [Rajapack Fita Adesiva Invisível/Transparente](https://www.rajapack.pt/material-escritorio/material-escritorio/fitas-adesivas-colas/fita-adesiva-invisivel-transparente_PDT01553.html) e [Chiromagnetic nanoparticles and gels / Science  19 Jan 2018: Vol. 359, Issue 6373, pp. 309-314 DOI: 10.1126/science.aao7172](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/359/6373/309)

Comment: Agradeço o envolvimento na questão mas o português formal foi corretamente descrito anteriormente e provavelmente quem formulou a questão da RAM a fez incorretamente..

Comment: @William a má formatação, pelo menos, podes resolver tu editando a resposta. Seria uma boa ajuda. :) Depois o autor da resposta, se achar as tuas críticas válidas, pode ele próprio tratar de arranjar referências. Quanto à acusação à outra pergunta, acho-a válida (embora pouco-ou-nada fundamentada).